# Скрытие блоков для моб. телофонов

Tags: блок

Как скрыть пару блоков для мобильных телефонов? ХЕЛП ХЕЛП.
Вот код
Вот код. уБРАТЬ DOSTAVKA, MENU, и убрать margin-left: 60px; margin-right: 70px;

```css
.container-1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

.container-1 div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.logo {
  flex: 9%;
}

.phone {
  flex: 10%;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.dostavka {
  flex: 13%;
}

.menu {
  flex: 65%;
}
```

Comment: Как скрыть пару блоков для мобильных телефонов? ХЕЛП ХЕЛП. Вот код. уБРАТЬ DOSTAVKA, MENU,  и убрать   margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 70px;

Comment: в обычном медиа запросе  скрыть и всё ...

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/google/blog/173861/